# iOS 11 - Weird UINavigationBar and UICollectionView behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, ios11

I have a `UINavigationController` the root view controller of which is a `UIViewController` with a `UICollectionView`. The collection has constraint to the left, right, bottom and top. I've checked the `prefersLargeTitles` attribute in the `UINavigationController`, so I have big titles. I expected that, during the scroll, the `UINavigationBar` would automatically collapse, but I had to disable the large titles in my root view controller and add this line of code in my `viewWillAppear` :

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
```

Then, I added also the search bar to the UINavigationBar, in this way :

```
let searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Everything is perfect, visually.

Now, when I scroll down, the `UICollectionView` suddenly stick to the `UINavigationBar` which collapses. When I tap on the status bar to go to the top of the collection, a white space appears between the large title and the status bar. Is there a specific procedure that, for some reason, I'm not following? Do you have any solution?

EDIT:
[Here you can find the video of the problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ety3vy76u5jlat3/weird_bug.mov?dl=0)

When you see the collection that sticks to the `UINavigationBar` I confirm you that it's happening in a unnatural way. The last "bug" happens when I tap on the status bar.

Comment: It would be helpful it you add some images to go with this.

Comment: @Xcoder I've added new details

Comment: It seems like you have got a NavigationController inside another one. Mind sharing your code?